# Hide text in PDF when printing

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

Is it possible to write some text in a PDF (more specifically a link), that will not be printed when sent to a printer, but only be shown in a screen reader?

If it's possible then any pointers to PDF writing .NET libraries that might have this as a feature is very welcome.

Comment: Our company has a PDF component suite for .NET called [PDFOne .NET](http://www.gnostice.com/PDFOne_dot_NET.asp). It can create PDF annotations that will be visible on the screen but not are rendered when sent to a printer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least two ways to achieve such an effect with PDF:

1. put the link or any element you do not want to print on a separate layer (in PDF spec lingo: "optional content") and set this layer as non-printable;
2. put the link into the PDF as an "annotation" and set this annotation as non-printable.